# parsing html, source code, javascript problem

Tags: c#, html

http://booking.travel24.com/index.php?KID=610000&&id=lmpergebnis&showresult=1&detail=zielgebiet&region=-1&ziel=-1&termin=20.02.2011&ruecktermin=17.03.2011&dauer=-1&abflughafen=46&personen=25;25&kategorie=-1&verpflegung=-1&zimmer=-1

I am trying to parse some HTML parts of this page, but when I check the source code I can not find this: "Tunesien, Marokko".

If I check with xdeveloper I can see this as html:

```
<a class="reglreg" href="javascript:s_hliste(20009);">Tunesien, Marokko</a>
```

but if i check source code of the page I can't find this. Why?

Comment: "sorse", "sourse", "souse" -- None of these variants is correct. The correct word is `source`

Answer (score 2):

If you view the source and search for "Marokko" you will see there are several places where it occurs (loaded as data in several JavaScript arrays).

It appears as if some of the content is produced dynamically through the JavaScript loaded onto the page.  That JavaScript builds HTML and changes the page to include the content you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first real question

> Why?

Because when you check the *source code* inside a browser, you'll get the original html code. Then javascript comes along and modify the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model#Web_browsers) which you can follow in any modern browser's console.

> can i get somehow whole source code
>   then? if i can not see it in browser
>   how can i see it?

To make it simple, it depends how you're trying to parse it. With what language?

Comment: i try to parse it with html agilitytoolkit (C# language)

Answer (score 0):

maybe the data is coming via AJAX call, so it's not there on the html at the start, but dynamically added to it.

if you need to parse this, you can try to "emulate" the ajax call yourself.